# TableToTable_conversion using PostgreSQL and ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, postgis, postgresql, error-000210

Currently, I am trying to convert a geodb to a table in my PostgreSQL db with arcpy as such. I've tried both with the parcels table being created and the parcels table not being created

```
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion("C:/Temp/geodb.gdb\parcels", "C:/../postgresconn.sde", "parcels")
```

I know my ../postgresconn.sde works because I can do other things such as FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion via...

```
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion("C:/../postgresconn.sde\database.public.area", "C:/Temp/geodb.gdb", "area", "", "", "")
```

The problem is in the TableToTable method, is that I cannot use database.public.area (dots are not allowed in that argument string)

I have set my searchpath on the PostgreSQL sql side to point to database.public hoping that it would just reference that schema.

The error I am getting ...

```
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output C:\...\postgresconn.sde\area
```

How can I make the method call TableToTable work in this scenario?

Comment: ArcGIS is incapable of creating tables with a schema other than that of the login name. Personally, I find `public` schema use to be a lazy alternative to proper database design, but I have no difficulty using whatever schema I desire if I'm willing to populate an interim table in the login schema, then populate my target table with an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` statement executed through an `arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute` cursor.

Comment: Can you further explain the login name? I create a login name that points directly to the schema that I am using? I am only using public right now to get this to work, as this is my first time trying to do stuff with arcpy and a database. Also, thanks for the help!

Comment: The [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/gdbs-in-postgresql/add-users-postgresql.htm) covers this. If you want to manage spatial data with ArcGIS, you need to create schemas that correspond to the logins. Using `public` will only generate problems.